# How to slice multindex columns in pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) object with 16 rows and 14671872 columns. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to slice this array in any reasonable amount of time on a quad core Dell T410 with 24GB of RAM.

I would just use the transpose of the array because that's **much** faster, but then I would have a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-hierarchical) on the columns, and I haven't yet found any documentation in Pandas showing how to use `MultiIndex`s as columns.

I thought about opening up an issue on the Github tracker, but I wanted to post here before I did that just in case I missed something totally obvious.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "how to use MultiIndex as columns"? What do you need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think .xs might do what you want.

To get all shank 1's (i.e. where the first level of the MultiIndex is equal to 1).

```
df.xs(1, axis=1, level=0)
```

This is pretty flexible if you need to cross-section by a different level of the MultiIndex as well.